# VMR9 Allocator/Presenter Sample 2D?

Tags: 2d, directshow, video-processing, renderer

Does anybody know a simple sample to use an custom allocator/presenter of the VMR9?
Or to get access to the default allocator/presenter.
I'm not interested in drawing on 3D-surfaces. I just want to have full control to stretching/shrinking/moving of varying input streams on the composition space of the VMR9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional custom allocator/presenter sample is \Samples\multimedia\directshow\vmr9\vmr9allocator from Windows SDK 7 (also, [mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468)). Compared to EVR presenter it is actually a simple one.

There is a scene and Direct3D inevitably involved anyway because that's VMR-9: it uses 3D device and surfaces for presentation.